# $|\zeta(2+it)| >y(t)$?

Tags: riemann-zeta, upper-lower-bounds

What is known about $|\zeta(2+it)| > y(t)$ where $t$ is real ?

It is clear that $|\zeta(2+it)|\neq 0$ and $|\zeta(2+it)|<\zeta(2)$ but do we have known sharp boundaries for this $y(t)$ ?

Comment: We know that $|\zeta(2+it)| > 1/\zeta(2)$. In fact $\inf_t|\zeta(\sigma+it)| = \zeta(2\sigma)/\zeta(\sigma)$ for $\sigma \ge 1$.

Comment: @reuns cool but why ?

Comment: Write the Euler product for $|\zeta(\sigma+it)|$ and $\zeta(2\sigma)/\zeta(\sigma)$ it should be evident

Comment: @reuns thanks. I will.

Comment: maybe i should delete it ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you saw that $|\zeta(\sigma+it)| \ge \zeta(2\sigma)/\zeta(\sigma)$ is evident from the Euler products.

$$\inf_t |\zeta(\sigma+it)| = \zeta(2\sigma)/\zeta(\sigma)$$ needs using that the $\log p$ are $\Bbb{Q}$-linearly independent so for any $m$ you can find $t_m$ such that $|1-p^{-\sigma-it_m}| > 1+p^{-\sigma}-1/m$ for $p\le m$.

Comment: Is that optimal ?

Comment: Optimal as what? $|\zeta(\sigma+it)|\ge (\prod_{p\le m} |1-p^{-\sigma-it}|^{-1})(\prod_{p>m} (1+p^{-\sigma}))^{-1}$

Comment: i meant if we can have sharper bounds proven

Comment: Can you clarify what you want? $|\zeta(\sigma+it)|$ oscillates in $(\zeta(2\sigma)/\zeta(\sigma),\zeta(\sigma)]$ in a very complicated way (almost periodic function whose pseudo frequencies encode the primes). Do you mean like the rate at which $\inf_{|t|\le T}|\zeta(\sigma+it)|$ converges to $\zeta(2\sigma)/\zeta(\sigma)$ ? It has good chances to encode the RH.

Comment: so it is complicated to improve you say ? Maybe a link to a sharper bound if one is published and proven.

Comment: What do you mean with "sharper bound"

Comment: yes how fast it converges to that zeta(2x)/zeta(x)

Comment: Check the theorems on the rate of upper (and lower) bounds on $\Re(s)=1$, how they encode the RH.

Comment: I see now , thanks @reuns